# What is the meaning of Noor of Allah

Tags: divine-attributes

I want to ask what does it means when we say Allah is noor does it means that Allah is a physical light but if we say that wont it be shirk beacuse Allah is not made of anything He is uncreated or does Noor of Allah means in terms of guidance.

Comment: there is a verse in the quran, widely known as the ayat al noor: its in a chapter - surah - of the quran - called surah al noor. you should check it out and the tafseer of it is online so you can read about it more.

Comment: Actually Imam Ghazzali has written a monography on this particular word. The book is called "Mishkāt al-anwār".

Answer (score -1):

do not interpret something based on physical. noor is the same as light which means it will give you light for your life's journey. may Allah give you a clear path